# Angular ngAnimate causes width animations to jump

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-animate

I am using Angular with `ngAnimate` for a couple of cases.  In another, I have a directive that is changing the width of the column (using Bootstrap `col-md-*` classes) and a simple transition that looks like this:

```
.column-view .column {
  transition: width 1s;
}
```

I am not explicitly using `ngAnimate` here, but it is certainly causing me grief simply for being included.  Basically, the transition jumps to zero before transitioning to the new width.  If I remove `ngAnimate` from my module, the transitions are smooth, but I need `ngAnimate` for other features in my app.

Can I disable whatever `ngAnimate` is doing to my plain CSS transition?  What can I do here to fix this?  Driving me crazy.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fnhr/1/) demonstrating the problem.  See the comments for instructions to reproduce.

Comment: I was playing with your original Fiddle, and what I found is that, upgrading to AngularJS 1.2.6, the "animation" is neither smooth nor funky... it simply toggles directly from start to finish state. See: http://jsfiddle.net/YUTT2/

Comment: Same behaviour with newest Fiddle, updating to AngularJS 1.2.6: http://jsfiddle.net/2fnhr/2/

Comment: Workaround for AngularJS 1.2.6 using undocumented classNameFilter: http://jsfiddle.net/2fnhr/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NOTE: I used current latest version (AngularJS 1.2.6) to investigate your issue.

I found there is a "blockTransitions" function being called internally, which does just that: it blocks transitions.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngAnimate/animate.js#L1099

If you comment the line linked above (the single line of the "blockTransitions" function body), the problem is solved.

As I can't tell if this is a proper solution (and probably it is not), I've just created a PR so they can properly resolve the issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5552

---

Also using latest version, there is a workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/2fnhr/3/

```
app.config(function($animateProvider){
  $animateProvider.classNameFilter(/^((?!col-md).)*$/);
});
```

This will only apply the ngAnimate stuff for classes which does not contain "col-md" on its name, thus turning off the ngAnimate for the Bootstrap classes in question.

Explanation of the regular expression here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/370290

Comment: +101  I wish I could vote this up 20 times.  Thank you.